# ¿Como borrar cache de Apache?

Tags: apache, xampp, phpexcel, cache

tengo un proyecto montado en un servidor externo funcionando correctamente desde hace algún tiempo, de este descargo un archivo excel utilizando PHPExcel todo funciona bien. Me vi en la necesidad de hacerle algunas actualizaciones al excel que arroja, trabajando en mi servidor local le realice cambios cuando crea el archivo lo descarga bien pero al abrirlo me dice:

"El archivo que intenta abrir tiene otro formato que el especificado por la extensión del archivo. Compruebe que el archivo no este dañado y procede de un origen de confianza antes de abrirlo.¿Desea abrir el archivo ahora?"

Cuando lo abro me aparecen muchos  símbolos, esto lo hace con todos los archivos de excel que descargo del servidor local ya que tengo otros proyectos que hacen esta funcion y me pasa lo mismo. tengo instalado xampp con apache.

revertir los cambio que le hice al archivo y me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Estuve investigando y al parecer hay que borrar la caché de Apache he intentado lo que dicen los post pero no logró borrar la caché. Espero me puedan ayudar se los agradesco de antemano.

Algunos de los link que visite son estos:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cache.html  (no entendi muy bien por que esta en ingles)

http://www.ubiquitour.com/LObERAmW/

https://techlandia.com/restablecer-memoria-cache-apache-como_481270/

Comment: has intentado con: htcacheclean ? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htcacheclean.html (En ingles)

Comment: Hola no lo habia intentado pero ya lo intente y sigue dandome el mismo error al descargar documentos excel, que crees que pueda ser? Ya borre la caché del navegador e intento con otro y persigue el error.

Comment: bueno yo haria estas cosas si no me carga bien el documento:  reiniciar apache, mirar el logs de errores de apache asi podria darme donde esta el problema :) puedes reiniciar el apache en una terminal y en otra terminal analizar los procesos que pas y cuando intentes entrar al sitio haces lo mismo (analiza los procesos que sucede en apache) asi podria ayudarte mejor a saber el error :) bueno yo haria eso :)

Comment: tambien podria ser la verion del apache (pero siendo honesto no creo) pero mira eso :) si la version de tu excel y apache son compatibles

Comment: dime la version de cada uno

Comment: la versión de apache es 2.0 y de excel es 2010, lo raro es que antes funcionaba bien y los que me descarga del servidor externo si los abre correctamente y es el mismo proyecto

Comment: mm dejame pensar :) y te comento :) me intereso la pregunta :/

Comment: @simon ya logre solucionar el problema, no era la caché de Apache si no de PHPExcel, investigando en la web encontre que hay que actualizar la versión de PHPExcel, lo hice y me daba un error en la línea de código 288 del archivo OLE.php dentro de la carpeta de Shared, el error dice algo respecto a la redundancia del ciclo tiene  continue, lo cambie por  el break y me dejo de dar ese error pero aun me marcaba el error anterior, encontré que hay que agregar la siguiente linea de codigo para limpiar los errores.  ob_end_clean(); //limpía cache.